# Rationale for const ref binding to a different type?

Tags: c++

I recently learned that it's possible to assign a value to a reference of a different type. Concrete example:

```
const std::optional<float>& ref0 = 5.0f;
const std::optional<float>& ref1 = get_float();
```

That's surprising to me. I would certainly expect this to work with a non-reference, but assumed that references only bind to the same type.

I found a pretty good chunk of the c++ standard which talks about all kinds of ways this works: https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5. But I would appreciate some insight: When is this ever desirable?

A particular occasion where this hurt me recently was this:

```
auto get_value() -> std::optional<float>{ /* ... */ }
const std::optional<float>& value = get_value();
// check and use value...
```

I later then changed the return value of the function to a raw float, expecting all uses with a reference type to fail. They did not. Without paying attention, all the useless checking code would have stayed in place.

Comment: For what its worth, it's likely the compiler will optimize out any unnecessary check on if `value` has a value. In [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/3d9b5d69P) you can tell by the generated assembly that the function is optimized to just calling `foo()` instead of actually evaluating `has_value()`.

Comment: Interesting, compilers saving the day for performance once again. But I was really more worried about dead code staying in the codebase. I can't even find a warning for this, not even in clang-tidy.

Comment: This is intended behavior, because `std::optional` is implicitly constructible from its held type. It's desirable so you can call a function like `void foo(const std::optional<float>& arg);` like `foo(10.0);`.

Comment: why not? With some crude oversimplification you can think of a constant reference like a constant value.

Comment: Good safety tip, thank you.  I do refactoring changes like this often, and also rely on the compiler to assist me on cleaning up all the collateral damage.  I'll have to keep in mind that implicitly convertible types won't trip the collateral damage.  (Even if benign, not what I want.) I'll have to pay attention to do a two-phase refactor to ensure a breaking change, then post-op clean that up to the final desired change.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's constructible yes. But I would have bet money that a reference assignment wouldn't construct anything ever

Comment: fwiw, with `const auto& value = get_value();` the checking code would have failed

Comment: Yeah but I prefer avoiding `auto` as it makes reading hard. But this seems to be a hard case for using `auto`.

Comment: Since C++20 maybe `const std::same_as<std::optional<float>> auto& value = ` if you want the type to be enforced by the declaration. This would need to be done for every declaration of a non-placeholder `const` reference (or rvalue reference) though to avoid the issue.

Comment: I try to keep `auto` to a minimum, but especially when changing return types during refactoring it turned out to be rather useful sometimes

Comment: @Basti You are correct, a reference is not an object, and its initialization does not create an object. But in this case it's the materialized temporary resulting from converting `float` to `std::optional<float>` that is being constructed. This is unrelated to the change of your function's return type from `std::optional<float>` to `float`. With the return type `std::optional<float>` the return value is constructed, with the return type `float` it's the converted value that is constructed. Either way one `std::optional<float>` is constructed and the reference extends its lifetime.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Mmh I'd say the optional would be constructed on the return statement and copy-elided? At least in my head, the proper semantics I'm not aware of. But I guess you're right. Still surprising to me

Comment: IMO, the behavior is desirable.  I want to be able to evolve my functions without the compiler to nitpick about type conversions that are provably correct.  The compiler will optimize out the checking code.  In C++20, if you depend on an interface you can add the constraint prior to 'auto' (e.g. std::ranges::range auto rng = get_range();)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic reason is one of **consistency**.  Since const-reference parameters are very widely used not for reference semantics but merely to avoid **copying**, one would expect each of

```
void y(X);
void z(const X&);
```

to accept anything, rvalue or otherwise, that can be converted to an `X`.  Initializing a local variable has the same semantics.

This syntax also once had a practical value: in C++03, the results of functions (including conversions) were notionally **copied**:

```
struct A {A(int);};
struct B {operator A() const;};
void g() {
  A o=B();       // return value copied into o
  const A &r=3;  // refers to (lifetime-extended) temporary
}
```

There was already permission to **elide** these copies, and in this sort of trivial case it was common to do so, but the reference guaranteed it.

Comment: I haven't seen it yet from the point of view of function parameters. Thanks!

Comment: If OP think `const` reference should not invoke conversion I think it's reasonable to guess OP would think the same thing (`const X&`) at parameter would also only accept `X` and prevent conversion. it's still consistent that way.

Comment: (yes I know OP seem to think it differently just above)

Comment: @appleapple I can't quite follow. Maybe to elaborate a bit: While I'm still technically confused as to how a `const X&` param does accept a `Y` type, with parameters I used this many times without thinking about it. I "know" that's how it works. But the explicit way with const ref variables (as opposed to parameters) is something I never used, at least I didn't notice I guess.

Comment: @Basti I'm just saying this answer doesn't really provide reason imo. the consistency can be achieved either way.

Comment: btw, I just realize the copy elision example doesn't apply to the question either, if it's different type then there is nothing to elide.

Comment: Right. It's more like I know from experience that it works with parameters. I've never made the connection. But now with the connection, I'm more willing to accept it. (Although I would still prefer to deactivate all of these implicit things with a compile switch)

Comment: @appleapple: Achieving consistency in the other direction seems so obviously undesirable (losing all conversions as a side effect of trying to avoid copies) that I didn’t even consider discussing it.  The copy elision bit is meant to explain why it was once useful to have this syntax; I’ll edit it to clarify that.

Comment: @DavisHerring maybe explain the undesirable would be a good addition to this answer, the "one would expect each of ..." just straight out conflict with what OP seems to want without providing evidence.

Comment: @appleapple: Sure, but that “seems to want” was obviously in a different context.  Anyway, I added a bit more there.